# Java regex hot to match meta tags content attribute value

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex and want it to match html meta tags content attribute and get its content. For example:

```
<meta name="description" content="Some website description.">
```

In this case to get

```
Some website description.
```

and nothing more.
In my case I am using this pattern:

```
private static Pattern siteMetaTagDescriptionAttributePattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"description\"(\\s*)content=\"(.*)\"");
Matcher matcher = siteMetaTagDescriptionAttributePattern.matcher(siteContentLine);
String siteDescription = "";
while(matcher.find()) {
  siteDescription = matcher.group(2);
}
```

And getting Till the end of the line, in this case this:

```
Some website description.">
```

What should I do to get only inner content of the content attribute, in this case

```
Some website description.
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider using Jsoup, if you are extracting data here and there in the page.

Comment: [Obligatory "don't do this" link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Hi there George. See @BoristheSpider link. It's hard to match HTML with Regex; however, you may *try* `(">)` at the end of your expression to see if that works.

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me..  Here's your example in a java regex tester - http://fiddle.re/mwvtf - `.group(2) = "Some website description."`

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272): please link to actual answers, not to non-answers.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using parser instead of regex. You can use for instance [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) like

```
String html = "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"Some website description.\">";

Document doc =Jsoup.parse(html);
System.out.println(doc.select("meta[name=description]").attr("content"));
```

output:

```
Some website description.
```

Comment: @downvoter If you found something wrong with this answer can you tell what is it? I would like to improve/correct it.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist:

```
(?<=name=\"description\" content=\")[^\"]*(?=\")
```

Comment: good regex, but I think you would need to escape the " in the char set `[^"]` also. Because he has the pattern enclosed in double quotes.  I think it needs to be like this : `Pattern.compile("(?<=name=\"description\" content=\")[^\"]*(?=\")");`